# Discord Chess.com Stats Bot?

Tags: discord, bots, chess

It's my first time creating a Discord bot and I'm trying to pull data from the chess.com API. I want the bot to return if a user won their last chess.com game when you type !chessresult user in the Discord channel. I know my bot is connected because I can get the bot to reply to text but I'm struggling to get it to pull the data. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands

PREFIX = '!'
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send('hello')

@bot.command()
async def chessresult(ctx, username: str):
    try:
        # Fetch the recent games of the user from the Chess.com API
        response = requests.get(f'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/{username}/games/archives')
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad responses
        archives = response.json()['archives']

        if not archives:
            await ctx.send(f"No games found for user {username}")
            return

        # Use the most recent archive to get the games
        last_month_url = archives[-1]
        games_response = requests.get(f"{last_month_url}/pgn")
        games_response.raise_for_status()

        # Extract games from the PGN
        games = games_response.text.split("\n\n\n")

        # Extract the result of the most recent game
        last_game = games[-2]  # The last item is empty, so take the second last
        result_line = [line for line in last_game.split("\n") if "Result" in line][0]
        result = result_line.split('"')[1]

        await ctx.send(f"Last game result for {username}: {result}")

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        await ctx.send(f"Error fetching data for {username}: {str(e)}")


bot.run('KEY')
```

I tried various methods and haven't gotten very far. It's my first time programming a bot.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead parse the json response instead of requesting a PGN file from the chess API in the second request:

```py
with requests.Session() as sess:
  
    # get the archives
    resp = sess.get(
        f'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/{username}/games/archives')
    resp.raise_for_status()
  
    last_game = resp.json().get('archives', [False])[-1]
    if not last_game:
        #error
  
    # get the last month
    resp = sess.get(f"{last_month_url}")
    resp.raise_for_status()
  
    game = resp.json().get('games', [{}])[-1].get('pgn')
    if not game:
        #error

# now session is closed
await ctx.send(game)
```

Long story short, I'm not able to recreate your error. It looks like the chess.com API does not require a key or authentication, so it's not that. You can add log statements and make sure that you're not encountering errors elsewhere that are being swallowed by one of your try/except statements.